# I receive error on dropdown onchange

Tags: php

I have a list with products and I have 3 dropdowns 
1.) I choose country
2.) I choose device
3.) I choose type

```
<div class="form-group">
 Country: <select style="width:200px;" class="form-control" onchange="search_offer();" id="country" name="country">
    <option value="all">All countries</option>
                         <?php

    foreach($countries as $key => $value) {

    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $key ?>" title="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($value) ?>"><?php echo $key ?> | <?php echo htmlspecialchars($value) ?></option>
    <?php

    }

    ?>
                          </select>
                           <script>
                                $('#country').val('<?php if (isset($_GET['country'])){echo $_GET['country'];} else { echo "all";} ?>');
                            </script>
                        </div>
                       <div style="padding-left:10px;" class="form-group">
                          Device: <select onchange="search_offer();" id="device" name="device" class="form-control">
                          <option value="all">All devices</option>
                          <option value="mobile">Mobile</option>
                          <option value="ince">Desktop</option>
                          </select>
                           <script>
                                $('#device').val('<?php if (isset($_GET['device'])){echo $_GET['device'];} else { echo "all";} ?>');
                            </script>
                        </div>
                       <div style="padding-left:10px;" class="form-group">
                          Category: <select onchange="search_offer();" id="category" name="category" class="form-control">
                        <option value="all">All Categories</option>
                        <option value="Download">Download</option>
                        <option value="Mobile Install">Mobile Install</option>
                        <option value="Pin-Submit">Pin-Submit</option>
                        <option value="Free Survey">Free Survey</option>
                        <option value="Trial Offer">Trial Offer</option>
                        <option value="Email/Zip Submit">Email/Zip Submit</option>
                        <option value="Social Action">Social Action</option>
                        <option value="Dating Site">Dating Site</option>
                        <option value="Credit Card Submit">Credit Card Submit</option>
                        <option value="Credit Score">Credit Score</option>

                          </select>
                          <script>
                                $('#category').val('<?php if (isset($_GET['category'])){echo $_GET['category'];} else { echo "all";} ?>');
                            </script>
                        </div>
```

I call changes with javascript:

```
function search_offer(){
            var country = $('#country').val();
            var device = $('#device').val();
            var category = $('#category').val();

            top.location='status_offers_smart_links.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>&country='+country+'&device='+device+'&category='+category;
        }
```

status_offers_smart_links.php have this:

```
    if ($_GET["country"] == "all" || $_GET["device"] == "all" || $_GET["category"] == "all"){

        $where = "";
        $execute = array();
    }


    if ($_GET["country"] != "all"){ 

            $country = $_GET["country"];

            $where = "WHERE countries=:country";
            $execute = array(":country" => $country);
    } 


    if ($_GET["device"] != "all"){  

            $device = $_GET["device"];

            if($device == "mobile" ){
            $where .= " AND device LIKE :device";
            $array = array(":device" => '%'.$device.'%');
            $execute = $execute+$array;

            } else {

            $where .= " AND device=:device";
            $array = array(":device" => $device);
            $execute = $execute+$array;
            }
    } 

    if ($_GET["category"] != "all"){    

            $category = $_GET["category"];


            $where .= " AND category=:category";
            $array2 = array(":category" => $category);
            $execute = $execute+$array+$array2;

    } 

$users = $db->prepare("SELECT id,category,title,description,photo,payout,epc,countries,device FROM offers ".$where);
$users->execute($execute);
$offers = $users->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Script is working fine, but when I select All countries -> Desktop -> All categories from dropdowns I receive error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND device=?' at line 1' in /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/status_offers_smart_links.php:59 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/status_offers_smart_links.php(59): PDO->prepare('SELECT id,categ...') #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/status_offers_smart_links.php on line 59
```

Line 59:

```
$users = $db->prepare("SELECT id,category,title,description,photo,payout,epc,countries,device FROM offers ".$where);
```

Same problem when I choose All countries-> All devices-> and something from category.

It is working fine if I choose Countries and devices and categories.
Or All countries and All devices and All categories

Any sugestion ? Any other informations I can provide!

Comment: `echo "SELECT id,... FROM offers ".$where;` - _check_ what the value you are passing into the function _actually_ is.

Comment: I'm betting that $_GET["country"] == "all", so the WHERE part of the clause is never being generated.

Comment: @CBroe I have selected All countries->Desktop->All categories and echo for $here is `AND device=:device`

Comment: You were supposed to output the whole thing, just as I wrote it - so that you can first of all realize _what_ is wrong with the query. And where the problem stems from, @aynber already pointed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easier way to do this would be to add the execute variables into one array, and add the individual where clauses into another. Then you can use implode to join all of those individual clauses with "AND" and get a properly formatted string, like this:

```
$wheres = array();
$execute = array();

if ($_GET["country"] != "all"){

    $country = $_GET["country"];

    $wheres[] = "countries=:country";
    $execute[":country"] = $country;
}

if ($_GET["device"] != "all"){

    $device = $_GET["device"];

    $wheres[] = "device LIKE :device";
    if($device == "mobile" ){
        $execute[":device"] = '%'.$device.'%';
    } else {
        $execute[":device"] = $device;
    }
}

if ($_GET["category"] != "all"){

    $category = $_GET["category"];
    $wheres[] = "category=:category";
    $execute[":category"] = $category;

}

$where = !empty($wheres) ? "WHERE ".implode(' AND ', $wheres) : ''; // Creates the string IF there are options to search for
$users = $db->prepare("SELECT id,category,title,description,photo,payout,epc,countries,device FROM offers ".$where);
$users->execute($execute);
$offers = $users->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Comment: Not working `Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed`

Comment: I forgot the array syntax on two of the `$wheres`. Try it now.